# Configuring ImageMagick in TYPO3

Tags: imagemagick, typo3

I cannot get ImageMagick to work in TYPO3 6.2.3

If I make a test file with this code:

```
<?
print "<pre>";
phpinfo();
print "</pre>";

system('/usr/local/bin/safe/convert --help');
?>
```

I get the PHP output and that doesn't tell anything about ImageMagick. But below that I get the help section from ImageMagick so ImageMagick is installed.

If I put /usr/local/bin/safe/ in the Image handling settings in TYPO3 backend the Test scaling images fail.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the [Imagick PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) to be able to use Imagemagick with the PHP language.

```sh
sudo pecl install imagick

# Or manually
curl -O http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.2.0RC1.tgz
tar zxvf imagick-3.2.0RC1.tgz
cd imagick-3.2.0RC1
phpize
./configure && make
sudo make install

# Add 'extension=imagick.so' to php.ini
```

The imagemagick module should show up in your `phpinfo()`, or be listed when executing `php -m`

**Edit**

TYPO3 is expecting to use the convert commands directly. No need for PECL's shared extension.

- Ensure the safe path is configured in your php.ini file (see [safe_mode_include_dir & safe_mode_exec_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php) )
- Updated TYPO3's  `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']` to map the convert program & location

```php
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im'] = 1;
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_path'] = '/usr/local/bin/safe/';
```

Example with [GraphicsMagick](http://wiki.typo3.org/GraphicsMagick) is a good reference. But `phpinfo` will not display any information about the Imagemagick version/install using this method.

Comment: In the Install tool under Current configuration I know hve this:
ImageMagick enabled:
    Yes 
ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick:
    ImageMagick 
ImageMagick path:
    /usr/local/bin/safe/ 
ImageMagick version:
    6.6.7-1 
IM5 effects enabled:
    0 (Blurring/Sharpening with IM 5+) 
GDLib enabled:
    Yes 
GDLib using PNG:
Freetype DPI:
    96 (Should be 96 for Freetype 2) 
File Formats:
    gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai 

I think TYPO3 has found ImageMagick, but I still get this error:

ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick handling is enabled, but the execute command returned an error.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer.

The error is:

Image generation failed
ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick handling is enabled, but the execute command returned an error. Please check your settings, especially ['GFX']['im_path'] and ['GFX']['im_path_lzw'].

Comment: It is only "scaling images" and "Writing gif and png" that is failing. "Combining" is working fine.

Comment: This is still not fixed.
In localconfiguration I have this:

'colorspace' => 'RGB',
  'im' => '1',
  'im_mask_temp_ext_gif' => '1',
  'im_path' => '/usr/local/bin/',
  'im_path_lzw' => '/usr/local/bin/',
  'im_v5effects' => '0',
  'im_version_5' => 'im6',
  'image_processing' => '1',
  'jpg_quality' => '80',